# align variable width font strings in ggplot2 ggrepel geom_label_repel

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggrepel

I am trying to use multiple line labels in `ggrepel::geom_label_repel`. It seems like the `geom_label_repel` wants to center all text - whereas I want to flush it left. `hjust = 0` does what I want with `geom_label`, but not with `geom_label_repel`. I created a function to do what I want by inserting spaces - but it will only work with monospace fonts.

Is there a way to get `geom_label_repel` to align left with variable width fonts?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)
site_timeline_dfx <- tribble(
  ~startDate, ~endDate, ~Event,
  1984, NA,   "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, sed, vestibulum, in lacinia erat arcu. Quis magnis sed phasellus ac",
  2001, NA,  "Vel cursus hac in. Nulla cum quam cum, amet tellus hendrerit.",
  2008, 2009, "Adipiscing ut pellentesque malesuada sit venenatis integer proin sapien. Scelerisque ipsum ut.")

my_xwrapFun = function(x, width = 75){
   x_wrap <- strwrap(x, width = width)
   i <- length(x_wrap)
   max_strln <- max(str_length(x_wrap))
   x_wrap <- encodeString(x_wrap, width = width, justify ="l")
   paste(x_wrap, collapse = "\n")
}

site_timeline_dfx <- 
  group_by(site_timeline_dfx, Event) %>% 
  mutate(Event_wrap = my_xwrapFun(Event))

ggplot(site_timeline_dfx, aes(x = startDate, y = 0.5, label  = Event_wrap)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_label(hjust = 0, size = 2) +
  xlim(c(1984,2050))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(site_timeline_dfx, aes(x = startDate, y = 0.5, label  = Event_wrap)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_label_repel(hjust = 0, size = 2) +
  xlim(c(1984,2050))
```

[image]

```
ggplot(site_timeline_dfx, aes(x = startDate, y = 0.5, label  = Event_wrap)) + geom_point() + 
  geom_label_repel(hjust = 0, size = 2, family = "mono") +
  xlim(c(1984,2050))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in the development version of `ggrepel` (version 0.8.1.9000).

Your code should now work as expected.

```
devtools::install_github("slowkow/ggrepel")

ggplot(site_timeline_dfx, aes(x = startDate, y = 0.5, label  = Event_wrap)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_label_repel(hjust = 0, direction="y") +
  xlim(c(1984,2050))
```

Comment: Thank you! No need to pad with spaces either.